# What do referees do during halftime?

Tags: american-football, basketball, officiating, nfl, nba

This question largely pertains to basketball and American football. I've seen footage from the team locker rooms during halftime where the coaches and players go over issues from the first half that need to be addressed, key statistics, etc.

I've often wondered what the referees do during the halftime break (other than get a breather).  Do they go over replays where they botched calls?  If so, do they have someone whose job it is to create the "highlight reel" of missed calls, e.g. a coach for the referees?

Comment: No clue what pro's do, but high school officials will usually spend some time recovering from the first half (grab some water, maybe a protein bar) and chat up the scorer's table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Especially in this age of 'on demand' media, NBA referees will take this time to analyze specific plays, fouls, flopping and potential arguments that might carry over to second half between two opposing players or between a particular referee and coach/player. The head referee will also critique his crew and make adjustments for second half. And as mentioned above its an opportunity to 'relax' and rehydrate.

Here's a good behind the scenes of NBA referee's halftime routines (around 2min mark): http://www.nba.com/video/channels/nba_tv/2013/04/17/20130416-monty-mccutchen-feat.nba/index.html

Comment: thank you for the link. It would be interesting if someone did a reality show and followed referees around for a while so you can see what they do.

Comment: That's an awesome video that perfectly answers what I was wondering.

Comment: @bob I'd definitely watch that

Answer (score -1):

Most referees use this time to reflect on how the first half went. They discuss the game with their Assistant Referee’s and are scanning for pointers. Some do this in order to hear from the Assistant Referee’s how well they are refreeing. Others will use reasoning to justify the mistakes they made or even cover their butts by making excuses.

Comment: I assume this is what they do, but do you have any reference, referee interview, etc that discusses this?

Comment: This link may help you.
http://www.scrrs.net/articles/what-should-a-referee-do-at-half-time/

Comment: that's an interesting article, especially where it points out not to look at film from the first half.  However, this is for a minor league rugby league, where stakes might not be so high.  I'm specifically looking for NBA and/or NFL.